# Какой регистр выбрать для имени переменных?

Tags: переменные, хороший-тон, имена

Допустим есть структура героя, в которой описаны его характеристики: `strength`, `dexterity`, `intellect`, `healths` - `сила`, `ловкость`, `интеллект` и `здоровье` соответственно. Но эти имена слишком длинные, если нужно использовать их в формуле подсчета урона, например:

```
Player.strength * 2 + Player.dexterity - ((Player.intellect * Player.healths) - Player.strength)
```

Формула, конечно, глупая, но суть передает. Я хочу использовать сокращения `ST`, `DX`, `IQ`, `HT`, так как правильно их сократить: в нижнем или в верхнем регистре? Вроде верхний регистр используют для констант, а если писать в нижнем, то плохо понятно, за что эти переменные отвечают. Интересует, как их назвать, следуя `Хорошему тону программирования`?

Comment: я смотрю сюда когда вопросы возникают) [Google Java Style](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s3.4-class-declaration)

Comment: Какой язык? В каждом свои собственные правила именования.

Comment: Это не переменные, а свойства объекта Player, поэтому если писать на JavaScript, то их так и надо записывать, как у вас приведено, без сокращений. Зато на документировании кода сэкономите. Идеальный код вообще читаем без комментариев, типа `if (savedSegmentValue < userRequiredStatus) storeAdditionalRecords(records, WITHOUT_WARNING)`. А с длинными словами прекрасно справится автодополнение кода в любом нормальном текстовом редакторе или IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменные _variable;
методы Method();

Пускай имена однозначно определяют переменные, хоть и длинные названия, зато прозрачно и понятно.

Я в своем коде если длинные записи встречаются пишу одну переменную в одной строке:

```
private int Method(int firstParameter, int secondParameter) {/*...*/}
public int GetResult(int anyMoreParameters)
{
   int this._result = this.Method(
          this._hp -
          this._someLongNameOfVariable,
          anyMoreParameters);
   return this._result;
}
```

И сразу видно где переменная класса, где метод, а где "внешние" переменные.

Comment: Никто не говорил, что речь о джаве.

Answer (score 3):

У каждого языка свои традиции именования.

Сокращать то, что и так из одного слова я бы не стал. На мониторе вполне помещается 200 - 260 символов без горизонтального скролла, так что не вижу в этом особой проблемы.

Что касается сокращений в принципе, то где-то была рекомендация в аббревиатурах из более чем двух букв писать буквы начиная со второй маленькими (например, GetHtmlPage, а не GetHTMLPage). Лично я его и к двухбуквенным сокращениям применяю - на мой взгляд, так читаемее.

Ещё есть вариант, использовать акронимы вместо простых аббревиатур.

Comment: Я еще дополню, что самые длинные названия переменных любой текстовый редактор прекрасно умеет подхватить и подсказывать, так что они в любом случае печатаются до половины, а потом `Enter`.

Comment: @SergeySnegirev, дополнить - это одно, но ведь потом читать придётся.

Comment: Так читать полные осмысленные названия переменных куда легче, чем набор из аббревиатуры, соперничающий с брейнфаком.

Comment: @SergeySnegirev, читать имена по 5-6 слов лично мне совсем не проще. Имеет смысл постараться уложиться в 1-2 слова, а для часто встречающихся сочетаний сделать сокращение.